# Webpages won't load after server reboot

Tags: iis, timeout, server, html, reboot

So last night I experienced a power outage which caused my server to reboot. Since then, I haven't been able to access any of my web pages. I keep getting the error "Connection Timed Out" and can't work out why. IIS is running and has been restarted. MySQL is running.

I've probably missed something simple but can't for the life of me figure it out, and after browsing the other questions I couldn't find any answers that seemed to work.

Thanks guys

Comment: Is MySQL on the same server? If yes - you should check any service(s) which may have stopped. Connection time out (I think) can also occur for web services. It would be good if you can post the exact error message or confirm if the error is occurring while making connection to db? Also try to connect to db using odbcad32.exe to determine if the problem is with webpage or with the db/network connection

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be solved by doing the following:

Establish a connection with your server and open cmd in Elevated Mode (Administrator).

Type in 'netstat -ano' to see all used ports at the server. If you notice any on port 80 configured tasks, while IIS is off temporarily, you should write down the PID and type in 'taskkill /PID **1234** /F' where /F means Forcefully and **1234** means the PID number. Then start your site(s) and keep me posted. I might have another solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers suggested, things I'll keep in mind next time.

What had happened on this occasion is that after the server had restarted, it had been assigned a new IP address so all of my rules and exceptions had to be modified to the new IP.

I feel like an idiot, but at least it got fixed